# Get sum of numbers inside Foreach loop in PHP

Tags: php, html

I want to sum individual record in a foreach loop.My table looks like this

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Person Name</th>
    <th>Balances</th>
    <th>Total</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <?php foreach($namePerson as $name):?>
    <td><?php echo $name->person_name ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $name->remaining_balance ?></td>
    <td></td>
   <?php endforeach ?>
</table>
Person Name  Balances        Total
Greg         234, 345, 45
Paul         234
Joe          2345, 345, 567
```

Now depending on person's record,He may have more than one balances.How to get the sum for example Greg's balances directly in a table without using MySQL aggregate SUM function?

Comment: If you're pulling that data from a database, you can see MySQL's `SUM()` aggregate function http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-sum/ - If not, then you'll need to add them up using `+` or if from an array, `array_sum()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php - Your question is a tad unclear.

Comment: You are missing a closing `?>` in your code.

Comment: As per your edit; you're still unclear. Where and how are those values coming from?

Comment: are those comma delimited values inside the row? or generated thru a query `group_concat`

Comment: @Fred-ii- ignore comments and answers own question... are we blocked?, lol :D

Comment: @Ghost yes those comma delimited values were inside the row

Answer (score 0):

By changing my code

```
<td>
 <?php $l =0; ?>
 <?php foreach($namePerson as $name): ?>
 <?php $l += $name->remaining_balance ?>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
 <?php echo $l ?>
</td>
```

now it works

Comment: This works if there's one person, one name in your result set ever. If the database call returns results from say 20 people, this method will give you a grand total, not per person.